# how to link a c++ library to a c++ source code when it has a specific linker script to compile?

Tags: c++, gcc, kernel, ld, i386

i have these files:-

```
/lib
    kernel.hpp
    kernel.cpp
main.cpp
```

when i use

`gcc -m32 -c main.cpp -lstdc++ -o main.o -llib/kernel.hpp`

it says

`[function name]([type of argument 1], [type of argument 2]) is not declared in this scope`

how to fix?

Comment: You want to use something like `gcc -m32 -c main.cpp -o main.o -Ilib' to compile main.cpp into main.o. You'll then want a different command to link main.o with everything else you need (kernel.o, libstdc++). The command you've got is very confused. Do you understand the difference between compiling and linking? (not trying to be mean here, it's an honest question)

Comment: @user888379 , when i organized my kernel source, i noticed functions from external user made libraries are not recognized. i need to fix that. that's all. i understand you're not trying to be mean here. i do understand that difference between compiling & linking.

Comment: So, kernel.hpp is a header file, and necessary for main.cpp to compile. That's why I suggested a -I flag for compiling main.cpp. You don't need to worry about linker flags when you're compiling main.o. kernel.cpp needs to have been compiled as well, providing either a kernel.o, libkernel.a or libkernel.so. Let's keep it easy and say that you have a kernel.o. You could then link together main.o kernel.o and whatever libraries you needed for your main.

Comment: note that i'm using c++, with function overloading.

Comment: or atleast tell me how to make gcc change the names of the overloaded functions. because the names are changed in the the kernel.o

Comment: If you're trying to compile c++, for starters you need to use g++, rather than gcc. That might be why you're getting an unhelpful compiler error. Good luck.

Comment: @user888379 , can i know what's the big deal with g++?

Comment: g++ is a c++ compiler. gcc is a c compiler. You are aware that c and c++ are different languages?

Comment: yes, c++ is a superset to c.

Comment: just tried with g++ @user888379 , but no new results

Comment: and new errors, typedefs are not linked. but in gcc, they were...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started writing a comment, but got to be too long, so we'll make it an answer instead. I don't think it in fact will answer your question, but it may point you in the right direction.

Let's clear up a misconception, c++ is not a superset of c; there are c constructs that c++ does not support. If your code is c++, you need to compile it with a c++ compiler. The problems you've been describing all indicate that compilation is failing; you're not at the point where the linker is involved. The compile command you provided in your question had a `-c` flag, which tells the compiler to stop after the compilation step - so there's no point in having a `-lstd++` flag in addition. For the compiler to find kernel.hpp you need a `-I` flag which indicates the directory where `kernel.hpp` can be found. That's what I was suggesting in my first comment.

To sum up, as shown in the original question, you're using the wrong compiler and the wrong flags for what you want to do.